# How can i add/subtract values in Graphql and store it in a collection (For eg. Like a wallet and transaction system)

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

I am a newbie in graphql and have a use case where I have to add or subtract all the transactions in real-time. For eg. Someone credited to an account the wallet of that person should be updated automatically. I have successfully written the code for creating a transaction but now i want to add/subtract the amount from a wallet. The wallet will be simple having total amount, credited, debited fields. Please help me with this. I am using express-graphql

```
createTransactionStudent: async(args,req)=>{
 
      
       try {
           const transaction = new Transaction({
               amount: args.transactionStudentInput.amount,
               creditDebit: args.transactionStudentInput.creditDebit,
               student: req.studentId,
               session: args.transactionStudentInput.session
           })
           let createdTransaction
           const result = await transaction.save()
           createdTransaction = transformTransactionStudent(result)
           return createdTransaction
       } catch (error) {
           console.log(`transaction error ${error}`)
           throw error
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: polling (for queries, `useQuery` option) or subscriptions, follow some chat example/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

You solution is graphql subscription. [Link here](https://dgraph.io/docs/graphql/subscriptions/) feel free to comment if you don't understand any part from the document.